# how to add object to specific index array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have example data like this

```
let datas = [
  { no : '1', list: [ {val: '1'}, {val: '3'},{val: '4'}] },
  { no : '2', list: [ {valNew: '11'}, {valNew: '13'},{valNew: '14'}] }
]
```

his expectations are like this

```
let datas = [
  { no : '1', list: [ {val: '1'}, { val: '2'}, { val: '3'},{val: '4'}] },
  { no : '2', list: [ {valNew: '11'}, {valNew: '13'},{valNew: '14'}] }
]
```

I've tried like this

```
const handleDuplicate = (index, idx, item) => {
let data = [...datas.listInvoice]
      data[index] = {
        ...data[index] = {
          ...data[index],
          invoices: [...data[index].invoices.slice(idx+1, 0, item)]
        }
      }
     
      setDatas(prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          listInvoice: data
        }
      })
}
```

I want to add an object to an array with a certain position, but it always fails and the array inside invoices becomes [], what is the solution for this case?

Comment: Please share the code which you tried.

Comment: The code you have written clearly doesn't work, but because we can't see that code we can't help. You should add the code to your question as a [mcve].